# tensorflow-gpu cannot be installed successfully

Tags: python, tensorflow, gpu, nvidia

I'm installing tensorflow-gpu-1.5 and CUDA v.9 and cuDNN v.7 but my tensorflow cannot be worked with gpu. when I check it as follow:

```
    from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
    print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

It return:

```
    name: "/device:CPU:0"
    device_type: "CPU"
```

I'm confused how can I get tensorflow working with gpu. What can I install step by step. I'm installing CUDA and cuDNN, Is there more requirement needed?
What about NVIDIA driver? I'm using windows10, python3.5, NVS 5200M.
Thanks.